# google analytics api loop

Tags: php, loops, analytics

In the following file, I get the data for the number of visitors the last day.
Now, I want to loop through the past 30 days and get the data from each day.

There are, I believe, three parts where I would need to change something.
Namely, `$results = getResults($analytics, $profile)`;, `printresults($results)` and further below:

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
      // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
      // for the last seven days.
       return $analytics->data_ga->get(
           'ga:' . $profileId,
           '1daysAgo',
           'today',
           'ga:sessions');
    }
```

Now I am unsure of how to accomplish this.
I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++{
   $results = '$results' . '$i';
   function getResults($analytics, $profileId){
       return $analytics->data_ga->get(
          'ga:' . $profileId,
          '$i' . 'daysAgo',
          '($i - 1)' . 'daysAgo,
          'ga:sessions');
   }
     printresults('$results' . '$i');
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any suggestions as to how to run this query multiple times? I think I am not doing it right. I might have to make an array, store the variable names for `$results` in this, and loop through that. But since `$results` comes back in several functions, how would I loop through this in all these functions?

Also, there is another question I have regarding this. Namely, `$results` only return something if there were visitors. Otherwise, it is not countable and it returns an error. I want to suppress this error and instead output `0`.

This worked for me with a function I wrote in another file, but once again not with the loops.

For completeness below the code for the google analytics:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>

    </script>
    <?php

    // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/google/vendor/autoload.php';

    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);



    function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
      // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

      // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
      $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

      if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $properties->getItems();
          $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

          // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
          $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
              ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

          if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $profiles->getItems();

            // Return the first view (profile) ID.
            return $items[0]->getId();

          } else {
            throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
      }
    }

    function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
      // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
      // for the last seven days.
       return $analytics->data_ga->get(
           'ga:' . $profileId,
           '1daysAgo',
           'today',
           'ga:sessions');
    }

    function printResults($results) {
      // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
      // the profile name and total sessions.
      if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print $sessions;
      } else {
        print "No results found.\n";
      }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very specific reasons to create an API loop to pull date for each data separately (eg [to avoid sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320017/google-analytics-reporting-api-getting-around-sampling/48326370#48326370)), don't do it as:

- It creates processing/API overhead for no reason (see alternative method below)
- You increase your chances of [reaching the API limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas)

To query daily data, just insert the [`ga:date`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date) dimension which will breakdown your data per day.

Also, you should use the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to make sure you queries work before trying to implement them, that will save you time:

[image]

Last but not least, [there is a data processing latency which can be up to 24 to 48 hours](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency), thus you might not see any data if you query only for yesterday or today.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But how would I structure this query then? Currently I have 
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'yesterday', 
       'ga:sessions');
}

but if I add the metrics here it returns errors. If instead I work with $optParams I get nonsensical data.  btw this is the hello reporting example.

Comment: `ga:date` is not a metric, it's a dimension. Here is an example for v3 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide#query) and an example for v4 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#dimensions_and_metrics)